# ¿Cómo puedo verificar si el src de una img coincide con una ruta relativa?

Tags: javascript, html

En mi página, tengo dos modos: oscuro y claro. Quiero que al hacer click en un elemento para cambiar el tema se cambie una imagen en forma "toggle". Es decir que cada vez que hago click cambie al modo opuesto.

La imagen original la puedo ver sin problemas. Pero cuando hago un `console.log` de la ruta, me trae el path con el http, mi direccion IP y toda la ruta declarada en `src`.

Entiendo que es por eso que nunca se cumple la condición en el if ternario.

¿Cómo lo puedo solucionar?

```
<input type="checkbox" id="dark-mode">
<img class="logo" src="GIFOS_UI+Kit_Desktop+y+Mobile/GIFOS-UI-Desktop+Mobile-Update/assets/logo-mobile.svg" alt="logo">
```

```
const darkMode = document.getElementById('dark-mode');
let logo = document.querySelector('.logo');
const darkLogo ='GIFOS_UI+Kit_Desktop+y+Mobile/GIFOS-UI-Desktop+Mobile-Update/assets/logo-mobile-modo-noct.svg';
const lightLogo ='GIFOS_UI+Kit_Desktop+y+Mobile/GIFOS-UI-Desktop+Mobile-Update/assets/logo-mobile.svg';

darkMode.addEventListener('click', () =>{
 
    logo.src = (logo.src === darkLogo)? lightLogo : darkLogo;

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Como muy bien verificaste, el `src` de una imagen es una ruta completamente calificada
(o sea, completa completa con todo desde el "http" con el dominio y la ruta completa).

Algo como `elementoImg.src == "../../ej.png"` nunca va a ser cierto.

Se arregla fácil, **convirtiendo la ruta relativa en absoluta** usando el constructor [URL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/URL):

```
const rutaParcial = '../bla-bla-bla/noct.svg',
      rutaAbsoluta = new URL(rutaParcial, document.baseURI).href;
```

y con eso ya podés usarlo para comparar contra el `src` de un elemento `<img>`.